# Out of the box matrix operator in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

**Background:** I'm running a finite difference scheme in Matlab. I want to differentiate a function of two variables `f(x,y)`. Instead, I have a matrix representation of it on the grid points `F(:,:)`. If `F` was a one-dimensional array, then the differentiation operator would have been a matrix `Delta(:,:)`, and differentiation would have been `F_tag = Delta*F`.

However, as `F` is a matrix, this becomes more involved. The basic approach is to represent `F` as an `n^2`one dimensional vector, and then represent `2d_Delta` as a n^2 on n^2 matrix. However, this might be a source for a lot of inefficiencies and bugs.

**My question:** Given an n*n matrix `F(:,:)` and a compatible matrix-operator `Delta(:,:,:,:)`, is there an out of the box implementation of running `Delta*F` as an n^2 matrix-vector multipication?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what operations you are talking about here, but I think maybe `bsxfun` can be helpful. `bsxfun(@times, F, Delta)` or `bsxfun(@times, Delta, F)`.

Comment: You have an out-of-the box function D = gradient(F); which works on multi-dimensional input. For custom operators you will have to write your own vectorized expressions, and bsxfun() is probably going to be helpful

Comment: @AiridasKorolkovas I've looked at `gradient` and `del2`.If I apply it iteratively, it allocates a new differentiation matrix at each iteration, or rather do something more efficiently?

Comment: If you want to differentiate very fast, you could do so using circshift:
A = randn(100,100);
dxA = 0.5*(circshift(A,[-1 0]) - circshift(A,[1 0]));
dyA = 0.5*(circshift(A,[0 -1]) - circshift(A,[0 1]));

Comment: @AiridasKorolkovas , In this example, dx = 0.5?

Comment: What I wrote is (A(i+1,:)-A(i-1,:))/dx, which is the central difference scheme and therefore dx = 2. You can also use a left- or right-difference scheme, (A(i+1,:)-A(i,:))/dx, in which case dx=1.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for the case of finite difference differentiation scheme, or any matrix-operator A which can be written by two matrices R,T such that for every matrix X

```
A(X) = RX + XT
```

Then the `kron` function is an excellent way to create the n^2 x n^2 matrix. Given a one-dimensional 2nd derivative matrix `D`, then the two-dimensional will be

```
Laplacian2D = kron(speye(n),D) + kron(D, speye(n));
```

For more details, I refer to [this great tutorial](http://www.math.uci.edu/~chenlong/226/FDMcode.pdf) by Long Chen.